# How to set the ispell dictionary for all files below a specific directory

Tags: emacs, ispell

How do I (automatically) set the dictionary (e.g. through an automated call to `ispell-change-dictionary`) to a specific language for every file below a particular directory?

Example: I'd prefer my standard directory language to be American English (e.g. by setting `(setq ispell-dictionary "en_US-wo_accents")` in my `.emacs` file) but I'd like to use British English for all files below (or: under) the directory `/home/werner/dissertation/`. And perhaps to Dutch for all files under `/home/werner/letters/`.

I am aware of the solution that prescribes to use `-*- ispell-dictionary: "english" -*-` at the first line of a file to set the dictionary for that particular file (described at [EmacsWiki.org](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractiveSpell)). I'd like to prevent to have to put this line on top of every new file that I make.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use something like (but this approach is more useful when you want to make something complex for given files):

```
(defun set-dictionary-hook ()
  (when (and (stringp buffer-file-name)
     (string-match "/dissertation/" buffer-file-name))
    (setq ispell-local-dictionary "ru")))
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'set-dictionary-hook)
```

or you can specify it in `.dir-locals.el` as described in [Emacs Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) - I think, that this will simpler than first approach, something like:

```
((tex-mode . ((ispell-local-dictionary . "english"))))
```

for files with specific modes, or

```
((nil . ((ispell-local-dictionary . "english"))))
```

for all files

Comment: +1 for Directory Local Variables. See also http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables